# How do I handle errors in a basic MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

Let's say I have a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `SetupBlocks`(

    IN myBlock VARCHAR(20)
)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO blocks (block)
    VALUE (myBlock);

END
```

What if I made a mistake in my code and DB setup, and the column `block` only allows for 15 characters but someone using my application has been able to get 20 characters into `myBlock`? I would get an error similar to this for this example:

```
Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column 'block'
```

Is there some way to handle any error (not just this one) and then report it into a table called `BlockSprocErrors` for monitoring within MySQL and within the stored procedure itself?

Just looking for a very basic example by modifying my procedure above.

Comment: Lookup handlers : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/declare-handler.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
        GET DIAGNOSTICS condition 1
        @SQLState = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, @SQLMessage = MESSAGE_TEXT; 
        SELECT CONCAT('Database error occurred, state - ',@SQLState, '; error msg - ', @SQLMessage) INTO @errorString; 

        CALL Collectors_Errors 
        (@errorString, 
        'Collectors_InsertAlbum', 
        barcodeApp, 
        usernameApp);
END;
```